# Types for Promise,.resolve and Promise.reject functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

What are correct types for resolve() and reject() functions of a Promise ?

I tried using `typeof...` but ts is still complaining

```
const reqs: Map<number, [typeof Promise.resolve, typeof Promise.reject]> = new Map();


.......


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reqs.set(id, [resolve, reject]));
});
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDelzm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Note that  `Promise.resolve` is a completely different type of function than the `resolve` you get in a constructor callback.

Comment: Uh, have you looked at the type declaration of `new Promise`? Have you asked your IDE what types it inferred for `resolve` and `reject` in your tuple?

Comment: Notice you don't need to put `reject` in that `Map` at all. Just call `resolve()` with a rejected promise if you need to reject a promise.

Comment: What is the type of the `new Promise` that you `return`? Please post the declaration of the surrounding function as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**naive solution**

You have to define the types that your promises will resolve or reject. The return value of both are `void`. Verify this example on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwI4QFwwLIEMAOAeMAVwFsAjBOAGhgG0AKANywBtCF0swBPAShgF4AfDAYgAlgBNqdCnBBx0AUThy4fISPESAusP4wwCAO6ZcdHgG4AUFdCRYkgTACMNu9BgAPJ4ZMAFOWIxCAQ6OkQIEGYGBGpEACsEYCh1YQBvKxgsxBQAOhCoOklqGgiomLiEROTtSysAX0sgA) -

```
const reqs: Map<number, [(value: any) => void, (error: Error) => void]> = new Map()

const id = 1

const x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   reqs.set(id, [resolve, reject])
})
```

**avoid any**

But what about that dreadful `any` type? Do you notice how `Map<...>` makes you specify the key and value types inside `...`? We essentially have to do the same thing for `Promise`. What type can be resolved? What type can be rejected? Let's solve that now -

```
type tdeferred<T> =
  [(value: T) => void, (error: Error) => void]

type tcolor = string

const colors: Map<number, tdeferred<tcolor>> = new Map()

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    colors.set(123, [resolve, reject])
})

const [resolve, reject] = colors.get(123)!
resolve("blue")              // color is valid
resolve({not: "accepted"})   // non-color invalid
```

Using generics means we can apply `tdeferred<T>` to other types, allowing you to build Maps of promises that resolve to various types -

```
type tdeferred<T> =
  [(value: T) => void, (error: Error) => void]

type tperson = {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const people: Map<number, tdeferred<tperson>> = new Map()

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    people.set(456, [resolve, reject])
})

const [resolve, reject] = people.get(456)!
resolve({ name: "alice", age: 33 }) // person is valid
resolve("blue") // non-person invalid
```

**reject other types**

If you want to reject something other than `Error`, you can rewrite `tdeferred` to use two generic parameters -

```
type tdeferred<T,E> =
  [(resolved: T) => void, (rejected: E) => void]
```

When you use it, you must now specify both types -

```
const people: Map<number, tdeferred<tperson, string>> = new Map()

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    people.set(456, [resolve, reject])
})

const [resolve, reject] = people.get(456)!
reject("you are rejected") // string is valid
reject(Error("you are rejected")) // non-string invalid
```

**deferred**

And what about those promises? You have the `[resolve, reject]` handlers stashed away in your Map, but where are you keeping the actual promise? Presumably after you lookup handlers, you will want to do something with the promised value -

```
type tdeferred<T> =
  [Promise<T>, (value: T) => void, (error: Error) => void]

function deferred<T>() {
    let resolve: (value: T) => void = () => {}
    let reject: (error: Error) => void = () => {}
    const promise = new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res
        reject = rej
    })
    return [promise, resolve, reject] as tdeferred<T>
}
```

Verify this example on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBMAmEDMICdkVgHgCoD4oF4AoKKAbQAVkB7AWwEsBnCbHAGigAoA3AQwBsArhABcULAEoCeLlTqx2HFNWSiAoqirJJ+abNgBdQoQQCAdgGNgdKqajwkqdCw6SA3sRJQ+EYFDQMqPi4RTl5BEIkpKBk5Ak5tPFcAXw8Sb180ACsIS1FFDRUodWUE6L04lyjk1KhzGwZfMGp6JjjTCAB3KEpaRggODn92LNL3T3G-CACg6HxJhhrxrJzfOayapPEatGABZFtSJt6mYanA4NPsy30oHgYYeyUnXEIUwlBIGDq+TTiG5DopgA5kY6qYGrVApoGKIALI8MAYUwCGgAIxQ7DgiCemGA300ODwc3aXXhYBcoKhyAYADomMAOABGABMAGZ2I9HLj8cgcC5JAB6AVQelQFmsmBUW52bFcyE-ZCU8G+Q4807TC6TK7AG5zHm0oE+Jls8QAQigQq8VCoAGsoAIwDAABbQTloWBQBC-cVGMA8mnAF2mDhg6YQGk-IGC4WR53QHm3BDAFBQOi+Rjzc7oIz+LMcABEqPC+ejmZm90D0COLQghCAA) -

```
type tcolor = string

const colors: Map<number, tdeferred<tcolor>> = new Map()

colors.set(123, deferred<tcolor>()) // set 123 to a deferred color

const [pcolor, resolve, reject] = colors.get(123)! // look up the deferred for 123

pcolor.then(console.log) // log the color after it is resolved

resolve("blue") // resolves the promise
```

**inferred deferred**

You can eliminate a touch of redundancy by inferring the type of `tdeferred` from the `deferred` constructor. I personally prefer the explicitly declared `tdeferred`, but I figured I would demonstrate typescript's `ReturnType` utility for sake of completeness. Verify on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKbFQJ065AeAFQD4AKASkQG8AoROxAG1SkRwGc4GA3VALkRJcAhgxB9EBCgF4iiLnBjJEUgdNmUAvrXpMWOAFapo-ElkxxM-AKLYLauQqUryy9VvqIICNiwAO5gFsYNlRlRDBUAHdEAAVA4NRCUhJ2ABpWVH17Gg8Pdk4eMPZtXIzDaCLMksQNMmqcKBBMJABtfzggkPT87lRuzKMoAF1EITZPbyhqLWooAE9fUKg0DGxcJLCAJWYmsAIFxPnFuGAUdDN14iJqWYPEKC8GCzCfTBgwAHMbrzAfCafMGx+ABZIS+PBgEABABGWHSy3Oa3wD04FiIshUEWioN85G+qMBADoQlASABGABMAGZ0isLsjHmjyBQAPQsxAkxCUqn3OCjM6rHBKRmYfG-FhtEX9Di9frlYZhEVsQkfZjk6lkACEiDZjDgcAA1ogQL57gALUJ0pGIYDPbk3XwiwlQC1gEg-GWoQlPD6s9k+82hEWjYBQLCIGAsYIZGU8ZA3Ho8EgAImholQyb9MYKqHGLtC7U6qGoQA) -

```
function deferred<T>() {
    let resolve: (value: T) => void = () => {}
    let reject: (error: Error) => void = () => {}
    const promise = new Promise<T>((res, rej) => {
        resolve = res
        reject = rej
    })
    return [promise, resolve, reject] as const
}

type tdeferred<T> = ReturnType<typeof deferred<T>>
```